# Rank versus Union

Tags: sql, rank

Hi i need to rank my rows according to the conditions met in where clause. So i wrote the query

```
select 1 as priority, usr_fname, usr_lname from core_users where usr_fname = 'John' and usr_lname = 'smith' and suburb = '0162'
union
select 2 as priority, usr_fname, usr_lname from core_users where usr_fname = 'John' and usr_lname = 'smith' and usr_title = 'Mr' 
union
select 3 as priority, usr_fname, usr_lname from core_users where usr_fname = 'John' and usr_lname = 'smith'
```

Now my TL insists i can use sql rank()/row_number() here. can someone guide how?

Comment: please tag your RDBMS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do use`row_number()`, you can get more than 3 values:

```
select usr_fname, usr_lname,
       row_number() over (case when suburb = '0162' then 1
                               when usr_title = 'Mr' then 2
                               else 3
                          end) as priority
from core_users
where usr_fname = 'John' and usr_lname = 'smith' ;
```

You can get equivalent priorities by using `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.  However, if all three groups are not represent in the data, the numbers will be "1" or "1" and "2".

However, a simpler version just uses a `case` expression and does what you intend:

```
select usr_fname, usr_lname,
       (case when suburb = '0162' then 1
             when usr_title = 'Mr' then 2
             else 3
        end) as priority
from core_users
where usr_fname = 'John' and usr_lname = 'smith' ;
```

Your version returns the same row multiple times -- once for each priority that it matches.  This returns each row only once, which I'm guessing is your actual intention.

Comment: Cool. I am using the simpler version :D